# UWP UserNotification AppInfo NotImplementedException

Tags: c#, push-notification, uwp, notifications

I trying to get all notifications from my device and i can't get Name of application.

```
            UserNotificationListener notificationListener = UserNotificationListener.Current;
            UserNotificationListenerAccessStatus accessStatus = await notificationListener.RequestAccessAsync();

            if (accessStatus == UserNotificationListenerAccessStatus.Allowed)
            {
                var notifications = await notificationListener.GetNotificationsAsync(NotificationKinds.Toast);

                foreach (var notification in notifications)
                {
                    // Here is exception                
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(notification.AppInfo.DisplayInfo);
                }
            }
```

I'm getting NotImplementedException when i appeal to AppInfo property.
Where am i wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Some notifications will fail to retrieve the app info. In the documentation, it's recommended to surround all code related to processing a single notification in a try/catch for this reason...

> We recommend surrounding all your code for processing a single
>   notification in a try/catch, in case an unexpected exception occurs
>   when you are capturing a single notification. You shouldn't completely
>   fail to display other notifications just because of an issue with one
>   specific notification.

If you identify which app the notification is from and let us know, we can try to fix the issue. These are often Win32 apps. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, i tried surrounding try/catch, but it just threw an exception :)
I tested Telegram and VK Notifications and problem the same.